# Instance member cannot be used on type - Swift error

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, instance

Let me explain my app so far...

I have Pokemon data stored in and array of dictionaries called `objects`.

1st VC -> user selects a Pokemon character, and the selected Pokemon's details are added to another Dictionary.

User then presses a button which takes them to 2nd VC (`collectionViewController`) -> the Pokemon data they selected is passed over as well and stored into a variable called `selectedPokemonObject`

If I `print(selectedPokemonObject)` I can see the data as expected that the user selected, so I know the data is passing to the 2nd VC.

In the `collectionViewController`, I want to show Pokemon that are of the same `"type"` to the Pokemon that the user selected.

I have created a variable that filters this:

`var filteredObjects = objects.filter{ ($0["type"] == selectedPokemonObject["type"])}`

This code doesn't work - it gives me the error:

`Instance member 'selectedPokemonObject' cannot be used on type 'CollectionViewController'`

I don't understand why this is.

I have seen a few questions already posted around this issue, but can't make sense of any of them - Their answers don't really help me with my issue, so I'd appreciate any help on this please. How can I use this in my code?

My full code is below for the `CollectionViewController`:

```
class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

var selectedPokemonObject = [String:String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   title = "Pokémon"

   print(selectedPokemonObject)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

    return 1

}

// MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

var filteredObjects = objects.filter{ ($0["type"] == selectedPokemonObject["type"])}.filter{ ($0["typeTwo"] == selectedPokemonObject["typeTwo"])}


override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return filteredObjects.count

}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    let object = filteredObjects[indexPath.row]

    cell.pokemonName.text = object["name"]!
    cell.pokemonImage.image = UIImage(named: "\(object["id"]!)"+"\(object["name"]!)")

    return cell

}
}
```

**UPDATE**

`objects` data is stored as a global variable in a file called `Data.swift` so I can access it anywhere.

Comment: Couple of questions. Where is `objects` declared? Is it a global variable? Also, they way you set up your filter statement there will make it so only pokemon with an EMPTY string for the `"typeTwo"` field but if they have a nil or any other string it will be filtered out.

Comment: @NSGangster I added the update to my question and amended the `"typeTwo"` error made ( I was playing around it with earlier) - thanks

Comment: did you try to save electedPokemonObject["type"] before filtering to check if that will work? and separate this two filters to go step by step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things I don't agree with your code but I'll start by helping you fix your error. Swift doesn't like you using instantiated variables to help you instantiate another variable. Swift has no way of knowing which one will be initialized first. Instead initialize both as empty, And set their value in `viewDidLoad()` which will run before your `UITableViewDataSource/Delegate` Methods. MAKE SURE `filteredObjects` and `objects` are the same structure. I. E. `[[String : String]]`

```
var selectedPokemonObject = [String:String]()
var filteredObjects = [[ String:String ]]()
```

So how you are filtering is wrong. You are basically saying "I filter out all pokemon except those that have the same first type as my pokemon. Then I filter them out again until I get ONLY the pokemon out of that small that have the same second type." Seeing as I know a little about pokemon and very few have the same type. This will give you a limited field of Poke's. Instead try something like this.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   filteredObjects = objects.filter { $0["type"] == selectedPokemon["type"] || $0["typeTwo"] == selectedPokemon["typeTwo] }
}
```

This filtering is saying if type one or type two match they will be in our filter list. Alternatively, you can try to add statements that if type 1 of selected pokemon matches type 2 of a pokemom it will go into filtered etc. etc.

Comment: Thanks. I get what you mean around the filtering. I have made you amendments but it's thrown 2 other errors now. Against the filter line of code, I get error: `Ambiguous reference to member 'filter' ` and then further down, in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method, against the line `let object = filteredObjects[indexPath.row]`, I get error: `Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : String]' with an index of type 'Int'`

Comment: Ah right, You need an array for your dataSource method's instead of a dictionary. I messed up on your data structure. One second while I fix some stuff.

Comment: @Nick89 updated some code. If it still doesn't work, Post code where you declare the `objects` array.